# Scheduling a Job that consumes multiple resources

Tags: optaplanner

I've got a problem which I think optaplanner may be able to solve, but I haven't seen a demo that quite fits what I'm looking to do. My problem set is scheduling IoT node usage for a testbed. Each test execution (job) requires different sets of constraints on the nodes it will use. For example, a job may ask for M nodes with resource A, and N nodes with resource B. It will also specify a length of time it needs the nodes for and a window in which the job start is acceptable. To successfully schedule a job, it must be able to claim enough resources to meet the job specific requirements (ie, hard limits).

Being new to optaplanner, my understanding is that most of the examples focus on only needing one resource per Job. Any insight into whether this problem could be solved with optaplanner and where to start would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, look at the (cheap time scheduling example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6KsveB6v-g&list=PLJY69IMbAdq0uKPnjtWXZ2x7KE1eWg3ns) and project job scheduling example.

The differentiating question is if when job J1 needs M nodes with resource A if whether or not any of those M nodes can also supply resource B, just not at the same time.

- If that's not the case, this is an easy model: you can threat resource A as a capacity like cloud balancing.
- If that is the case, it's a complex model (but still possible), for example the jobs are chained or time grained (=> planning var 1) and each job has tasks which are assigned to nodes (=> planning var 2). All of this is likely to need custom moves for efficiency.

Comment: It's going to look like the second (ie, there will definitely be cases where the M nodes supply both resources A & B and can supply both to a job, but can't handle two concurrent jobs).

There will also be cases where the constraints call out specific nodes (ie, to repeat a specific test which failed in the same environment).